# Debian Buster - Avahi uninstalled itself, and can no longer use hostname on Windows PC

Tags: linux, windows-10, debian

This is a bit of a weird one.

I had a Debian 8 system, which I updated to Debian 9 and then Debian 10. After this was completed, I could no longer access it via the hostname, and instead have to use the IP address.

After a bit of poking, it seems like avahi somehow uninstalled itself. I've tried reinstalling it, but it's still not working.

When I run avahi-discover, I get the following error;

```
(avahi-discover:18009): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:40:28.574: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

EDIT: `sudo service avahi-daemon status`;

```
    ● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor pre
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-24 15:54:44 BST; 4min 53s ago
 Main PID: 552 (avahi-daemon)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."
   CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
           ├─552 avahi-daemon: running [Scotty-Server.local]
           └─575 avahi-daemon: chroot helper

Oct 24 15:54:44 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Service "Scotty-Server" (/servi
Oct 24 15:54:47 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Joining mDNS multicast group on
Oct 24 15:54:47 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv
Oct 24 15:54:47 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Registering new address record
Oct 24 15:54:49 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Joining mDNS multicast group on
Oct 24 15:54:49 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv
Oct 24 15:54:49 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Registering new address record
Oct 24 15:54:57 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Joining mDNS multicast group on
Oct 24 15:54:57 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: New relevant interface docker0.
Oct 24 15:54:57 Scotty-Server avahi-daemon[552]: Registering new address record
```

Comment: Did you try installing it again using this resource?   https://gist.github.com/davisford/5984768

Comment: Yes, that was the exact command I used.
I've added the output of `sudo service avahi-daemon status` to the OP

Comment: Solved it - Once everything was installed and working, the issue was windows. Rebooting my windows machine seems to have sorted everything.

Weird!

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't Debian, it was Windows.

Restarting windows seems to have fixed the issue, whatever it was.